# Angular4 issue with http requests

Tags: javascript, angular, callback, return-value, angular4-router

In my Angular 4 application I am developing an oath guard service. There I want to check if the token is live and if not, user needs to log in again.

Below are the functions I am using to achieve what I want:

```
isLogedIn(){

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/check-token?token="+this.currentUser.token).map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(response => {
          let logedinUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
                if(response.message == "_successful" && localStorage.getItem("currentUser") != null){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
             },err =>{ 
                console.log(err); 
                return false;
           });

}
```

but the thing is in auth gurd function I cant get the exact out put value of this function. Bellow is my auth gurd function:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    console.log(this.userService.isLogedIn());
    if (this.userService.isLogedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
        queryParams: {
          return: state.url // curent url as a parameter to the login page
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
```

When I use  `console.log(this.userService.isLogedIn());` it prints the Subscriber object not the return value. How do I return the value from  isLogedIn() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're returning a subscription indeed. `

- `this.http.get(...)` is an `Observable`;
- `this.http.get(...).map(...)` is an `Observable`;
- `this.http.get(...).map(...).subscribe(...)` is a `Subscription`;

The `subscribe` method returns a `Subscription`, not the `return something` that is inside `subscribe` routine.

What do I suggest you: return the observable itself in the guard (`canActivate` accepts `Observable<boolean>` as return). Do not call `subscribe` at `isLogedIn()`:

```
isLogedIn(): Observable<boolean>{

return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/check-token?token="+this.currentUser.token).map(res => res.json())
.map(response => {
      let logedinUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
            if(response.message == "_successful" && localStorage.getItem("currentUser") != null){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
         });
}
```

Note I call `map` twice: the last one is to manipulate your response to return a boolean. Finally, at `canActivate`:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

  return this.userService.isLogedIn().do(response => {
    if (!response) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
        queryParams: {
          return: state.url // curent url as a parameter to the login page
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

I insert the operator [`do`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html), which is an independent callback, to manage your routing.

Answer (score 0):

your function should be like

```
isLogedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/check-token?token=' + this.currentUser.token)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            const response = res.json();
            return response.message == "_successful" && localStorage.getItem("currentUser") != null;
        }).catch((error: Response) => {
            return false;
        });
}
```